# awk catch missing columns

Tags: awk

I have a file which looks like this:

```
SOME,DESCRIPTIONS,OF,THE,COLUMNS
0,93,50127,0,49592,1,49592,1
100,195,107336,0,106491,2,107077,2
200,298,178492,3,170578,24,172045,13
...
2590,0
```

And I'm trying to add a ratio column based on the 4th ($4) and 6th ($6) columns.

I've written:

```
awk -F "," 'NR==1{$9=",ratio"}NR>1{if($4==0) $9 = "10000"; else $9 = ($6)/($4)}' $FILE
```

As you can see, on the very last line, the output is malformed and missing columns, so running the command results in a `division by zero` error.

Is there some way to skip over malformed lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN  { FS=OFS="," }
NR==1       { $9="ratio" }
NR>1 && NF>3{ if($4==0) $9 =10000; else $9 =$6/$4 } 
{ print }' infile
```